# How to set up DNS for Ingress with MetallLB not work?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, metallb, kubernetes-dns

Previously, I tried to make it work ingress using NodeIP.
[How to make My First ingress work on baremetal NodeIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69141018/how-to-make-my-first-ingress-work-on-baremetal-nodeip)
It did not work too, perhaps the problem is the same as now, that I did not configure it correctly.

I gave up this option and tried MetallLB + Ingress

!What I did in both cases:
!I installed DNS via /etc/hosts only on my work machine.

```
10.0.57.28  cluster.local test.local ingress.example.com dashboard.cluster.local test.cluster.local test.com
```

Installation metallb With Helm:

```
helm repo add metallb https://metallb.github.io/metallb
helm install metallb metallb/metallb -f values.yaml
```

values.yaml

```
configInline:
  address-pools:
   - name: default
     protocol: layer2
     addresses:
     - 10.0.57.28-10.0.57.29
```

Using Helm¶ install Ingress Controller:

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

get svc -A

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default                ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.233.3.75     10.0.57.28    80:30963/TCP,443:32376/TCP   19s
```

make service

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
   name: ingress-hello
   namespace: dev
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "test.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: hello-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

Make ingress:

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
       name: ingress-hello
       namespace: dev
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: cluster.local
        http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: hello-service
                port:
                  number: 80
            path: "/hello"
            pathType: Prefix


curl -D- http://cluster.local/hello
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sat, 11 Sep 2021 17:26:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 146
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

kubectl get svc -A

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default                ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.233.3.75     10.0.57.28    80:30963/TCP,443:32376/TCP   25m
default                ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.233.13.161   <none>        443/TCP                      25m
default                ireg                                 ClusterIP      10.233.34.105   <none>        8080/TCP                     8d
default                kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.233.0.1      <none>        443/TCP                      10d
dev                    hello-node-service                   NodePort       10.233.3.50     <none>        80:31263/TCP                 19h
dev                    hello-service                        ClusterIP      10.233.45.159   <none>        80/TCP                       2d6h
kube-system            coredns                              ClusterIP      10.233.0.3      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       10d
kube-system            metrics-server                       ClusterIP      10.233.27.232   <none>        443/TCP                      34h
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper            ClusterIP      10.233.29.129   <none>        8000/TCP                     10d
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard                 ClusterIP      10.233.36.25    <none>        443/TCP                      10d
```

Check "hello" pod

service_hello_Node.yml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-node-service
  namespace: dev
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

curl -I 10.0.57.35:31263

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 11 Sep 2021 17:28:46 GMT
Content-Length: 66
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

kubectl describe pod ingress-nginx-controller-fd7bb8d66-mvc9d

Please help me why ingress does not work. Maybe I need to customize the DNS in a particular way?

Service and Ingress in same Namespace. Ingress Controller in different.

I look at the ingress controller logs - there is nothing, is this normal?

kubectl describe pod ingress-nginx-controller-fd7bb8d66-mvc9d

```
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                      Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                      -------
  Normal  Scheduled  19m   default-scheduler         Successfully assigned default/ingress-nginx-controller-fd7bb8d66-mvc9d to kuber-node-01
  Normal  Pulled     19m   kubelet                   Container image "k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.0.0@sha256:0851b34f69f69352bf168e6ccf30e1e20714a264ab1ecd1933e4d8c0fc3215c6" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    19m   kubelet                   Created container controller
  Normal  Started    19m   kubelet                   Started container controller
  Normal  RELOAD     19m   nginx-ingress-controller  NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
```

kubectl get pods -A

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default                ingress-nginx-controller-fd7bb8d66-mvc9d     1/1     Running   0          22m
default                ireg-685d4b86fb-rwjpj                        1/1     Running   1          27h
default                metallb-controller-748756655f-ss6w7          1/1     Running   0          93m
default                metallb-speaker-2tf86                        1/1     Running   0          93m
default                metallb-speaker-6xht6                        1/1     Running   0          93m
default                metallb-speaker-9wjrm                        1/1     Running   0          93m
default                metallb-speaker-b28fv                        1/1     Running   0          93m
default                metallb-speaker-jdv4z                        1/1     Running   0          93m
default                metallb-speaker-svwjz                        1/1     Running   0          93m
default                metallb-speaker-xd22w                        1/1     Running   0          93m
dev                    hello-app-78f957775f-7d7bw                   1/1     Running   1          27h
dev                    hello-app-78f957775f-hj9gb                   1/1     Running   1          9h
dev                    hello-app-78f957775f-wr7b2                   1/1     Running   1          9h
kube-system            calico-kube-controllers-5b4d7b4594-5qfjc     1/1     Running   1          27h
kube-system            calico-node-7mcqc                            1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            calico-node-9trpd                            1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            calico-node-fl55n                            1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            calico-node-g9zxw                            1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            calico-node-j8fqp                            1/1     Running   0          10d
kube-system            calico-node-jhz72                            1/1     Running   0          10d
kube-system            calico-node-rrcm4                            1/1     Running   0          10d
kube-system            coredns-8474476ff8-552fq                     1/1     Running   0          27h
kube-system            coredns-8474476ff8-h45sp                     1/1     Running   0          27h
kube-system            dns-autoscaler-7df78bfcfb-xzkg9              1/1     Running   0          27h
kube-system            kube-apiserver-kuber-master1                 1/1     Running   0          10d
kube-system            kube-apiserver-kuber-master2                 1/1     Running   0          34h
kube-system            kube-apiserver-kuber-master3                 1/1     Running   0          34h
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-kuber-master1        1/1     Running   0          10d
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-kuber-master2        1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-kuber-master3        1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            kube-proxy-52566                             1/1     Running   1          27h
kube-system            kube-proxy-6bwrt                             1/1     Running   0          27h
kube-system            kube-proxy-fxkv6                             1/1     Running   1          27h
kube-system            kube-proxy-kmjnf                             1/1     Running   1          27h
kube-system            kube-proxy-pnbss                             1/1     Running   0          27h
kube-system            kube-proxy-tf9ck                             1/1     Running   1          27h
kube-system            kube-proxy-tt4gv                             1/1     Running   0          27h
kube-system            kube-scheduler-kuber-master1                 1/1     Running   0          10d
kube-system            kube-scheduler-kuber-master2                 1/1     Running   0          10d
kube-system            kube-scheduler-kuber-master3                 1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            metrics-server-ddf5ffb86-27q7x               2/2     Running   0          27h
kube-system            nginx-proxy-kuber-ingress-01                 1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            nginx-proxy-kuber-node-01                    1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            nginx-proxy-kuber-node-02                    1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            nginx-proxy-kuber-node-03                    1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            nodelocaldns-2clp8                           1/1     Running   0          10d
kube-system            nodelocaldns-b4552                           1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            nodelocaldns-hkffk                           1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            nodelocaldns-jflnt                           1/1     Running   0          10d
kube-system            nodelocaldns-k7cn7                           1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            nodelocaldns-ksd4t                           1/1     Running   1          10d
kube-system            nodelocaldns-xm544                           1/1     Running   0          10d
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-856586f554-thz5d   1/1     Running   1          27h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-67484c44f6-mgqgr        1/1     Running   0          9h
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add the following content to the ingress -  annotation.
Then the ingress controller starts to see the DNS addresses.

```
  annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
```

Also, for convenience, changed path: / to a regular expression:

```
            - path: /v1(/|$)(.*)
```